# Solr search seved keywords in text

Tags: solr

all.

I am writing an application where I want to scan some text with set of keywords. I am using SOLR and indexing my keywords as indexes (keywords also contain various fields like title, description, etc).

Now question is, how  free text data can be searched with keywords via SOLR query.

For example:

I have a Solr item with keyword "word 1" and if free text is equal something like "bla bla word 1 bla bla" I should get return this item.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I fully understood your question, but if you ask if solr will retrieve the document: 'word 1' when querying 'bla bla word 1 bla bla' then it depends on your schema.

The default operator is defined by setting `<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND|OR"/>` in your schema.

Usually the default operator is `OR` so it will retrieve your document, but I suggest that you'd take a look at [Solr schemaXML wiki page](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Default_query_parser_operator).

Answer (score 0):

It dependes on what FieldType you have used while indexing the data.
FieldType consists of analyzer and there are two analyzers.
one for query and other for index.

if your index analyzer has correct tokenizer and filter it would index the keys in correct way .
Same is with query analzer.

an example of fieldType

```
<fieldType name="text_rev" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
   </fieldType>
```